# How to calculate radiation length of muon from radiation of electron $X_o=37 \rm gm/cm^2$?

Tags: particle-physics

I want to calculate the radiation length of muon. I understand I have to use formula of bremsstrahlung because it is a particle but I do not understand how

Answer (score 0):

There is a section about Passage of Particles Through Matter in the [Particle Data Group review](https://pdg.lbl.gov/), where you may find something (even though it is very technical). But according to this quote from there, it may be irrelevant to define the radiation length of muons:

> Radiative effects dominate the energy loss of energetic muons found in
> cosmic rays or produced at the newest accelerators. These processes
> are characterized by small cross sections, hard spectra, large energy
> fluctuations, and the associated generation of electromagnetic and
> (in the case of photonuclear interactions) hadronic showers.
> As a consequence, at these energies the treatment of energy loss as a
> uniform and continuous process is for many purposes inadequate.